# CPU looks overclocked even though its in a laptop with base settings

Tags: laptop, cpu, overclocking, clockspeed

I am running a resource-hungry program on my laptop and when I looked at the CPU clock speeds I saw this:
[image: power-hungry program]

The clock speed is almost half a GHz above base!  I have a Dell Inspiron 13 5000 series with a Core i7-7500U.  I have never messed with my bios except for an occasion where a co-installed a version of Linux.  I am worried that my CPU might overheat and die although the CPU doesn't seem to thermally throttle.  Maybe it has turned thermal throttling off? (I don't know a lot about clock speeds and thermal throttling so I don't even know if this is possible.)  Does anyone know what might've happened and how to turn it on or off?

Comment: "Maybe it has turned thermal throttling off?" - **This cannot be done.**  Your processor is designed to boost it's frequency.  Your processor, if it was overheating, would be unable to boost it's frequency.  **What you describe is perfectly normal.**

Answer (score 1):

Almost all processors self-throttle these days. No user intervention required.
It is not 'broken' it is doing its job. If it gets too hot it will throttle down again to cool itself.

CPU Spec at [Intel Ark](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95451/intel-core-i7-7500u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html) which looks like it's got one more step to go, it's not at full clock yet.

Comment: I get that the CPU is not a full clock yet, but WHY is it over base clock? Shouldn't the clock speeds stay at the 2.90 GHz (base clock) since I haven't changed any settings?

Comment: No, as I already said & also Ramhound in his comment, They are designed to self-throttle.